# Unable to access magento without /index.php/ in the URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, htaccess

I have fully downloaded a magento 1.9.1 instance and it's DB which was running on a server into my computer and trying to get it up and running using WAMP server. everything looks fine **except** that I can't browse any page in both front-end and back-end unless I put /**index.php**/  in the URL. (if I don't, I get the 404 error)

I have tried enabling **rewrite url** module in WAMP,and clearing cache but that didn't help at all.

**Is there anything I can do to get this fixed?**

I notice I don't have the .**htaccess** file on my machine. Can this be the reason? If yes, do I have to place **htaccess** file in every single folder or just the root folder of magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with .htaccess file. Take the .htaccess file from this git repo and put that file inside your Magento root directory [Git Repo](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror).

Put this piece of code inside the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```