# Magento 1.9 pages not found without index.php

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page

I am working on Magento 1.9.2.1 and setup a copy of website in its root directory in a folder. ex www.website.com/folder

I am not able to access the pages except home page without index.php.
back-end is also not accessible without index.php.

> What i have already tried.
>
> 1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155399/62788
> 2. CONFIGURATION: System -> Configuration -> (General ->) Web:
>      Use Web Server Rewrites: YES

Please Guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache server then please add a default magento .htaccess file to your magento root directory.

Comment: Please check this link and confirm everything is fine or not https://www.keycdn.com/support/htaccess-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding website into /folder you should try following updates in .htaccess file inside /folder

```
#RewriteBase /folder/
```